# Dataframes vs Datasets in spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

When should we use dataframes and datasets in spark?
Both support `scala` and are more efficient than RDDs when talking about structured and semi-structured data.

However, Is it ambiguous to choose datasets rather than dataframes ?
Is the only advantage of datasets over dataframes TypeSafety?